# get data when using ajax call with setTimeout()

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I’m new to ajax and I don’t know if what I’m doing is correct:

This is my PHP controller:

```
public function checkAllApprove(){
    $userX = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $result = $this->lawmodel->startBattle($userX);
    foreach($result as $row){
        $data['getData'] = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->challengerID);
        if($row->challengerApprove == "0"){
            echo "Wait for your challenger to approve battle!";
        }
        else if($row->challengerApprove == "1"){
            $data['content'] = 'sampleBattle';
            $this->load->view('include/template2', $data);
        }   
    }
}
```

This is my Ajax call:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var auto_refresh = setTimeout(
 function ()
 {
      $('#acceptedBattle').load('<?php echo "http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkAllApprove"?>').fadeIn("slow");

   },5000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

  </script>
```

Ajax call will not display on what is inside in my controller function. I need to display the data of my controller. I dont know if that is the correct way to use the ajax function or is there's another way using ajax with `setTimeout()` to call my controller?

Comment: How do you expect `php` to be executed in client site? Load will take the url to hit. So it will be `load("http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkAllApprove")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your PHP function:

```
public function checkAllApprove(){
    $userX = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $result = $this->lawmodel->startBattle($userX);
    foreach($result as $row){
        $data['getData'] = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->challengerID);
        if($row->challengerApprove == "0"){
            echo "Wait for your challenger to approve battle!";
        }
        else if($row->challengerApprove == "1"){
            $data['content'] = 'sampleBattle';
            $this->load->view('include/template2', $data);
        }   
    }
}
```

There is no `return`. So nothing ever comes out of the function. Except maybe that `echo "Wait for your challenger to approve battle!";`

Unclear how your larger framework works, but maybe this line:

```
$this->load->view('include/template2', $data);
```

Should be this instead with a `return`:

```
return $this->load->view('include/template2', $data);
```

Or perhaps an `echo` based on that other `echo`’s behavior?

```
echo $this->load->view('include/template2', $data);
```

Comment: thanks! im gonna this it..is this will also call the data to my view? from my controller?